Does the Roman Catholic Church consider a prayer of thankfulness part of one of the seven sacraments or an additional sacrament?
For example, thanking God for food.

For everything created by God is good, and nothing is to be rejected if it is received with thanksgiving, for it is made holy by the word of God and prayer. (1 Tim 4:4–5,ESV)


Why do you think it should be a sacrament? Does any church or theologian consider it as one?

In the Catholic Church, a sacrament is a process whereby holy grace is transmitted to someone, typically through another agent, such as a priest. How does a "prayer of thankfulness" relate to that? Or are you referring to some other denomination's definition?

The answer below is good.  The Greek word for grace means gift and isn't the proper response to receiving a gift to give thanks.  Thus, it should be the response to every gift of grace.

TL;DR: No.

Catholic definition
Per Catechism of the Catholic Church section on Sacraments in general (CCC 1113-1131) summarized in CCC 1131,

The sacraments are efficacious signs of grace, instituted by Christ and entrusted to the Church, by which divine life is dispensed to us. The visible rites by which the sacraments are celebrated signify and make present the graces proper to each sacrament. They bear fruit in those who receive them with the required dispositions.

there are 5 aspects of the identified seven sacraments listed in CCC 1113:

Instituted by Christ (CCC 1114-1116)
By the church and for the church, with the church acting as priestly people (all believers), but performed by ministerial priesthood to guarantee authenticity in liturgical action (CCC 1117-1121)
Presupposes faith on the part of the recipient so they are efficacious (CCC 1122-1126)
To confer the grace of salvation (CCC 1127-1129)
As an advance deposit of eternal life (CCC 1130)

Exegesis of 1 Tim 4:1-5
In contrast, in 1 Timothy 4:1-5 Paul warns against false teachers who forbid marriage and demand abstinence from certain foods (v. 3), so in v. 4-5 Paul countered that

both are good as long as
they are received as God's good and sanctified creation (cf  Gen 1 where God pronounced all He created "good" and blessed/sanctified them, and Gen 2:18-25 where God instituted marriage), and
with thanksgiving by prayer

Comparison between thanksgiving prayer and Catholic sacrament
As we compare the 5 general aspects of the Catholic Church's understanding of sacrament above, with the concern of Paul in 1 Tim 4:1-5, we see that what we are thankful about in the latter is a lot more general, i.e. having to do with God's good creation, rather than with God's provision for our salvation from the Fall, which include the misuse of God's good creation.
While of course there are plenty of thanksgiving in the celebration of each sacrament, the character of a sacrament is both remedial (restoration) and means of grace that flow from the work of Christ, than thanksgiving over our lives and God's provision through creation.  Thus, the bread of life from heaven in the Eucharist is for sanctifying us rather than unconsecrated bread for our natural nourishment.  We are thankful for both, but for different purpose.  Also, the thanksgiving prayer for the former is public while thanksgiving prayer before a meal can be private.
Conclusion
Yes, a prayer of thanksgiving IS a part of each of the seven sacraments (see the liturgical text), and a general prayer of thanksgiving does fit #1 (Christ instituted the Lord's prayer) and #3 (needs faith).  But a general thanksgiving prayer lacks the specificity of a sacrament: #2 (as priestly action by one to another, ex opere ex operato), #4 (has to do with salvation), and #5 (part of the hope for eternal life).  To be a Catholic sacrament, it has to possess all 5 aspects.
The Catholic sacrament of marriage is an odd one among the seven though, since the spouses are the ministers of grace rather than the ministerial priest. A baptized Catholic can also perform baptism or give absolution in an emergency.
Even so, #2 still applies in those 3 instances, by virtue of the priesthood of all believers.  Still, a general prayer of thanksgiving is direct to God, which lacks the sacramental character of mediation by a priest.
